# Can't Get ACE.OLEDB to work to display excel file in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, excel-2007, oledb

I have the following code in which I'm trying to load an Excel file into a datagridview using OLE.DB. The program runs, but the datagridview is still blank. Any idea why? I'm running Excel 2007 on a 64x machine, so I changed the project build to x86, but it still isn't working. Ideas?

```
Public Class Records

Dim excel_app As Excel.Application
Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ColumnCount, RowCount, TotalCellCount As Long
Dim yearstamp As String = _
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")
Dim exeDir As New IO.FileInfo(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName)
Dim xlPath = IO.Path.Combine(exeDir.DirectoryName, "Records.xlsx")

Public Function QueryExcel(ByVal sheet As String) As DataTable
    'use this connection string for .xlsx files
    Dim cs2007 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=@FILENAME;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"

    'use this connection string for .xls files
    Dim cs2003 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=@FILENAME;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", sheet)
    Dim cs = cs2007.Replace("@FILENAME", IO.Path.Combine(exeDir.DirectoryName, "Records.xlsx"))
    'get contents of xls file
    Using cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(cs)
        Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)
            Dim t As New System.Data.DataTable
            Try
                cnn.Open()
                t.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            Catch ex As Exception
                'handle exception. in this case i'm just returning an empty table
            End Try
            Return t
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
Private Sub Records_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim t2013 = QueryExcel("2013")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = t2013

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried checking to see if the application is running an exception? also you dont actually need different connection strings for .xlsx and .xls as `cs2007` will work for .xls

Comment: I'm getting a first-chance exception around here "Dim t As New System.Data.DataTable
                Try
                    cnn.Open()
                    t.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    'handle exception. in this case i'm just returning an empty table
                End Try
                Return t"      But, the grid still pops up (blank though)

Comment: Can you post the exception message? - The reason the grid pops up is the command line to display it is outside of the try catch statement, the reason it is blank is the table is empty due to the exception.

Comment: "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred"      I'm not sure the blank grid showing is because of the try catch statement because I changed the statement to display a MsgBox that said Lose if it failed and it did not. But, alas I've decided to yet again ditch the Ole DB method and stick with my import by cell loop since Ole DB has yet to ever work for me. Now, I'm just trying to figure out how to use the same datagridview across multiple tabs in a tab control, but have the information update in the datagridview to show the information is the different excelsheets